# Crosscompilation project on Linux for Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, archlinux, mingw-w64

I would like to compile C++ http server on my archlinux using drogon framework for Windows.
I read about possible way on official cmake docs:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html

I have installed all required mingw64-*** utilities and faced problem that after specialized -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE cmake no more can find Drogon package with find_package() command.

here is my main CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(lru_server CXX)

include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)

check_include_file_cxx(any HAS_ANY)
check_include_file_cxx(string_view HAS_STRING_VIEW)
check_include_file_cxx(coroutine HAS_COROUTINE)
if (NOT "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}" STREQUAL "")
    # Do nothing
elseif (HAS_ANY AND HAS_STRING_VIEW AND HAS_COROUTINE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
elseif (HAS_ANY AND HAS_STRING_VIEW)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
else ()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif ()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    lru_cache/
    endpoints/
)

target_sources( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    lru_cache/lru_cache.cpp
    endpoints/ApiController.cpp
)


find_package(Drogon CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Drogon::Drogon)


if (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD LESS 17)
    # With C++14, use boost to support any, string_view and filesystem
    message(STATUS "use c++14")
    find_package(Boost 1.61.0 REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Boost::boost)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD LESS 20)
    message(STATUS "use c++17")
else ()
    message(STATUS "use c++20")
endif ()

aux_source_directory(controllers CTL_SRC)
aux_source_directory(filters FILTER_SRC)
aux_source_directory(plugins PLUGIN_SRC)
aux_source_directory(models MODEL_SRC)

drogon_create_views(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/views
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
                           PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/models)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
               PRIVATE
               ${SRC_DIR}
               ${CTL_SRC}
               ${FILTER_SRC}
               ${PLUGIN_SRC}
               ${MODEL_SRC})
```

also toolchain file:

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH 
    /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32    
    /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/lib/cmake
    /usr/lib/cmake/Drogon)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
# set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

cmake -S /my_project_dir -B build-lru_server-MinGW64 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/toolchain-mingw.cmake

without -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE all works (using clang++ compiller).

the cmake output error:

```
[20:01:45] @archlinux bin$ cmake -S /var/repo/lru_cpp_rest_server/lru_server -B /var/repo_build/lru_cpp_rest_server/build-lru_server-MinGW64 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/var/repo/lru_cpp_rest_server/lru_server/TC-mingw.cmake
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:29 (target_sources):
  Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
  to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  An interface source of target "lru_server" has a relative path.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Drogon" with any
  of the following names:

    DrogonConfig.cmake
    drogon-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Drogon" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Drogon_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Drogon"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Why when i using toolchain drogon and other installed on system files not foundable?

UPD:
after advices from @Tsyvarev

```
[22:19:01] alxndrklbk@archlinux bin$ cmake -S /var/repo/lru_cpp_rest_server/lru_server/ -B build-lru_server-MinGW-Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/var/repo/lru_cpp_rest_server/lru_server/TC-mingw.cmake
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include any
-- Looking for C++ include any - found
-- Looking for C++ include string_view
-- Looking for C++ include string_view - found
-- Looking for C++ include coroutine
-- Looking for C++ include coroutine - not found
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:29 (target_sources):
  Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
  to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  An interface source of target "lru_server" has a relative path.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Jsoncpp: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include  
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call
```

Comment: Why do you place `find_package` call into the **toolchain file**? And the following line `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Drogon::Drogon)` will never succeed in the toolchain file: the target `lru_server` is not created yet. As your error message doesn't contain this line, I guess that you run `cmake` with **different toolchain file**. Please, update your question post to include the toolchain file you **actually** use.

Comment: What is **installation path** of the Drogon package, which you expect CMake to find with `find_package(Drogon CONFIG REQUIRED)` call? Note, that installation suitable for native (Linux) compilation is not suitable for cross-compiling for Windows. And remove your random settings of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable: this variable effectively re-roots every search path. That is, when `find_package` looks for a file under `/usr/lib/cmake`, in your case it searches that file under `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/usr/lib/cmake`, `/usr/lib/usr/lib/cmake` and other nonsense paths which are not existed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i really post actually toolchain file

Comment: @Tsyvarev about CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM read at cmake documentation, so have added that

Comment: "about CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM read at cmake documentation, so have added that" - So you have read that some variable ([CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html)) uses another variable ([CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html)), and you assign **random values** to that another variable, do you? As I said above, such setting just makes `find_package` to find nothing. If you are not sure what this setting means, then remove it.

Comment: Can you link your repo? I'll try to cross-compile it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev values was not a random, in documentation was added mingw64 compilers and PATH's, so i just changed it to my locations, CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM stay without changes

Comment: @HolyBlackCat link to my repo: https://github.com/AlxndrKlbk/lru_cpp_rest_server

Comment: "in documentation was added mingw64 compilers and PATH's" - No, documentation adds paths which "where is the **target environment** located" . This is neither where cross-compilers are located, nor the PATH where target's programs can be found. BTW, below the toolchain example there are more detailed explanations of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and other variables: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html#finding-external-libraries-programs-and-other-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully cross-compiled your project with [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) (which I'm the author of).

It takes care of the toolchain file, so you don't need to write one yourself.

- First, install quasi-msys2 prerequisites (this is for Ubuntu 22.04, adjust for Arch):

  ```bash
  sudo apt install make wget tar zstd gpg wine
  # Install Clang and LLD
  bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"
  ```

  Note Clang, I'm going to be using it instead of GCC for this.
- Then install quasi-msys2, and the necessary packages from it:

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
  cd quasi-msys2 
  make install _gcc _jsoncpp _zlib _openssl
  env/shell.sh
  cd ..
  ```

  Here we install MSYS2 GCC for the libraries it provides. Also, since Drogon is not in MSYS2 packages, we have to build it ourselves, and need to install its dependencies: jsoncpp, zlib, openssl.
- Clone Drogon:

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon
  cd drogon
  git submodule update --init --recursive
  cd ..
  ```
- Patch out their bugs:

  - Rename headers and libraries to lowercase, since our setup is case-sensitive, unlike native Windows:

    ```bash
    find drogon -type f -exec sed -i -E 's/(Windows.h|WinSock2.h|Rpc.h|Rpcrt4|Crypt32|Secur32)/\L\1/g' {} +
    ```
  - Add missing headers:

    ```bash
    (echo -e '#include <dirent.h>\n#include <sys/stat.h>'; cat drogon/trantor/trantor/utils/AsyncFileLogger.cc) | sponge drogon/trantor/trantor/utils/AsyncFileLogger.cc
    ```
- Build Drogon:

  ```bash
  CXXFLAGS='-Wno-defaulted-function-deleted -Wno-unqualified-std-cast-call -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override' cmake -S drogon -B drogon-build
  cmake --build drogon-build -j`nproc`
  cmake --install drogon-build
  ```

  Here we silence a few Clang warnings here.

  We also install the resulting library into our quasi-msys2 installation. Normally I would advise against this, since this mixes your files with those from msys2 packages.

  But it makes things easier. And you can quickly reset quasi-msys2 to a clean state using `make reinstall-all`, if you mess something up.
- Lastly, clone and build your project:

  ```bash
  git clone https://github.com/AlxndrKlbk/lru_cpp_rest_server
  cmake -S lru_cpp_rest_server/lru_server/ -B lru_server-build
  cmake --build lru_server-build -j`nproc`
  ```
- And run it (this uses Wine):

  ```bash
  lru_server-build/lru_server.exe
  ```

---

Reported issues:

- https://github.com/an-tao/trantor/issues/267
- https://github.com/an-tao/trantor/issues/268
- https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/issues/1655
- https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/issues/1656

Comment: cmake --build drogon-build -j`nproc` command give this error:                              Z:/home/alxndrklbk/.local/usr/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/cstdlib:79:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   79 | #include_next <stdlib.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: #define _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_NEXT_C_HEADERS
 79 #include_next <stdlib.h>
 80 #undef _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_NEXT_C_HEADERS                                                               --------- but it definitely located at alxndrklbk@archlinux UCRT64 ~/.local/usr/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0
# ls -lha | grep std
-rw-r--r-- 1 alxndrklbk alxndrklbk 2.3K июн 23 02:04 stdlib.h

Comment: @AlexanderKolbeko Do you have Clang (and LLD) installed? It seems quasi-msys2 didn't find one, and falled back to running MSYS2 GCC with Wine. It's supposed to work too, and I'll look into why it doesn't, but building with Clang is a superior option anyway, because it doesn't have the added slowness of WIne.

Comment: @HolyBlackCay when i launch quasi_msys2 env have this on console output: "Success! Will use wrappers for the native Clang." and this suspicious message "[WARNING] Didn't find symlink `/ucrt64` -> `/home/alxndrklbk/.local/usr/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64`."

Comment: @AlexanderKolbeko This is strange. Can you share the output from `env/shell.sh` to pastebin? And also a few lines from `cmake --build drogon-build --verbose`.

Comment: @AlexanderKolbeko Do you perhaps have a stale `drogon-build` directory from a previous attempt? Can you delete it and retry? CMake should be picking up Clang (`win-clang++`) as the default compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCay https://pastebin.com/6K4bksfB  as i understand i had run initial cmake run without lld package, because make mistake and install llvm instead lld. tested .exe with hellodrogon.exe on localhost, all work. Thank you really so much. Do you need help with your open-source project's? I will be glad to take part in your projects and learn from you

Comment: @AlexanderKolbeko Thanks for the suggestion. :) Quasi-msys2 is basically done, there's nothing left to do on it (except for fixing this bug). And I don't have any other active projects going on.